# Using External Content Type Pickers with Boolean fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs

I have a SQL table with three fields - a unique ID I don't care about, a description, and a Boolean indicating whether or not the record is 'current'.  This table is setup as a fairly standard External Content Type using SharePoint 2013 BCS.

There are only a hundred or so records in this table, with about 90 'current', and about 10 'non-current'.

I want to be able to set up the picker for the Read List operation to offer either:

- Only 'current' records; or
- Only 'non-current' records.

When I try and set this up, I don't seem to be able to enter a value for the picker *(see the image below where it says 'parameter')* - it seems to want to leave this up to the user, which in the case of a string field would seem fine.  This doesn't apply to Booleans though.

[image: ECT Read Item filtering definition screen]

Answer (score 0):

Filters are useful when you have dynamic filtering, like Query String or picking value from any control.. I would suggest you make a single Read List operation and than create two different Views for your requirement